# Get Background Color of WordPress admin page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, colors, admin

I need certain colors from the admin page for my plugin. Is there a way in php to get the currently active color of #wpadminbar or #adminmenu .wp-submenu or some other style of an element? I don't need the schema name(base,focus,current)!

For example code:

```
<?php
$wpadminbar_background_color = //get_background_color???;
echo 'Current admin bar background color for your theme: #' . $wpadminbar_background_color;
?>
```

I only need the color of certain elements.

Comment: Either you need to read the CSS file or from the client side, you need to post the colors for the specified element to PHP using Javascript.

Comment: I can with javascript, but I need it with php. I'm testing with: DOMDocument::loadHTML, but....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to use small trick. WP has function `get_user_option('admin_color')` which will give you name of your color scheme. You instead of calling just this function, can use this:

```
$admin_colors;
add_action('admin_head', function(){global $_wp_admin_css_colors; $admin_colors = $_wp_admin_css_colors;});
```

and now by calling

```
$admin_colors[get_user_option('admin_color')]['colors']; // array(0 => #1d2327, 1 => #2c3338, 2 => #2271b1, 3 => #72aee6)
```

you will get admin scheme colors.
So usage in your code:

```
<?php
$admin_colors;
add_action('admin_head', function(){global $_wp_admin_css_colors; $admin_colors = $_wp_admin_css_colors;});
$wpadminbar_background_color = $admin_colors[get_user_option('admin_color')]['colors'][0]; // array(0 => #1d2327, 1 => #2c3338, 2 => #2271b1, 3 => #72aee6)
echo 'Current admin bar background color for your theme: #' . $wpadminbar_background_color;
?>
```

**EDIT**

Actually you are getting with code above just colors of pallete displayed in admin settings. Easiest option how to get actual colors, is this. You have in $admin_colors not just colors but also url of css file (doesn't work on default theme). So you can get content of css file and then regex search in this file for value.

```
$content = file_get_contents($admin_colors[get_user_option('admin_color')]->url);
preg_match('/#wpadminbar{[^}]*background:(#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6})[^}]*}/', $content, $admin_color);
echo $admin_color[1];
```

Comment: Samuel Krempasky, I already tested this same approach, but it doesn't work. In this way, 4 colors in the array and the colors for icons, base, focus, and current can be extracted from the code. Wordpress has 9 admin color schemes, fresh, light, modern, blue and so on..., but they don't all share ['colors'][0]; color in the array as the "main color".
For example for:
fresh-default ['colors'][0] = #1d2327 : wpadminbar = #1d2327,
blue ['colors'][0] = #096484 : wpadminbar = #52accc,

If additional plugins are installed that enable additional amin color schemes, it becomes even worse.

Comment: @sanels Maybe my edit will work for you, just take note that it doesn't work for default light theme.

Comment: I tested. It doesn't work with Default, Sunrise, and I get wrong values ​​for Ectoplasm and Midnight. For additional admin color scheme plugins in 90% of cases I get good values. Hmm... is it possible to get a value every time or should I stop researching?

Comment: @sanels sorry, I forgot in `[a-fA-F0-9]` for f/F so it didn't work for themes with f in color... My bad, please try my hopefully last edit.